# Speech Recognition in C# not installed

Tags: c#, windows, speech-recognition

I don't really know if this is a windows problem or a C# problem but I was trying to mess around with c# and speech recognition where my program would understand simple voice commands but everytime I run I get an error saying:
"A first chance exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
Additional information: Er is geen herkenner geïnstalleerd. "

I am using a dutch version of Windows 7 and I don't have Windows Speech Recognition (I checked at "ease of access")

but how can I set my c# voice recogniser to english? Do I need to install anything or is it impossible for my program to ever work because I run a dutch version?

```
 SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.Visible = false;

        Choices radios = new Choices();
        radios.Add(new string[] { "stubru", "mnm", "joe" });

        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Append(radios);

        // Create the Grammar instance.
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

        sr.LoadGrammar(g);
        sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognized);
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a language pack for english first? http://windows.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7  For convienance I linked to the dutch version of the languagepacks...  [Extra info](http://superuser.com/questions/317374/do-i-get-additional-speech-recognition-engines-after-installing-windows-7-langua)

Comment: I went to the site but I can't download the english language pack.. it says "ontdek hoe" ("discover how") instead of download.. I think I can't change my language because I don't have an ultimate windows edition, but it just can't mean that anybody without an ultimate windows edition will be able to run my program? Or use an english speech recognition is his c# project?

Comment: It looks like it. The language seems to be baked in for Home and Premium editions. Strange.

Comment: I tried using the SpeechrecognitionEngine to get a "culture" so I can get it to set to english but still getting error :s

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you load the Dutch speech recognizer from [Dictus](http://www.dictus.dk/), you can specify a dutch locale and you're off & running.  (Checking the web page makes it appear that it's fairly expensive, which is odd, since I've worked with them, and was under the impression that they had extensive Gov't funding.)  It may well be cheaper to buy an Windows 7 Ultimate upgrade.